# Get multiple keywords in a range using VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am working on large excel files and i need a way to automate the work using VBA code, Here is a brief of what I do and what i need:

I have a column containing titles and i search manually for a certain value and then i write the value down in another column, and then i search for another value and repeat the same step, if i found 2 values then i write it down in the same cell separated by comma,

What i need is a script that lookup the first value in the table of values and search for it in the Title column and retrieve the value in adjacent column, then repeat this step for each value in the table.

See below Example:

Table 1: containing values to search for

```
Values
VBA
Excel
Data
Format
Sum
Replace
```

Table 2: Containing Titles

```
Title
Excel VBA Code to find and Replace
VBA/ Excel determine if cell has a data validation error with vba code
Excel VBA - Finding a relative range of data
Excel VBA code to negate values
```

And the result would be values found, as in the image below:

[image]

I hope this is clear enough, I need it as dynamic as possible.
I appreciate any help
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  As many new members misunderstand, Stack Overflow is not a code for me service, but a place where people can bring existing code that is not working and get help with specific problems in that existing code.

Comment: Hint: You would probably want to look at `InStr` to achieve what you require...

Comment: `Find` is listed in your results, but not in your list of Values.  Also, do you really want duplicates in your results column?  eg see row3 columnB

Comment: Also, why does row 2 not include Replace as a keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
Sub Keyword()
    Dim Words As Range
    Dim strText As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Words = Range("A2").Resize(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)  '-->change "A" here to your Value column
    Set strText = Range("C2").Resize(Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)  '-->change "C" here to your Title column
    For Each c In strText
        For Each r In Words
            If InStr(1, UCase(c), UCase(r), 1) > 0 Then
                c.Offset(, 1) = c.Offset(, 1) & ", " & r
            End If
        Next r
        If Len(c.Offset(, 1)) > 0 Then c.Offset(, 1) = Right(c.Offset(, 1), (Len(c.Offset(, 1)) - 2))
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This will give you output as below:

[image]

And if you want to use this code as a function then try the following:

```
Function Keywords(Words As Range, strText As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Words
    If InStr(1, strText, c, 1) > 0 Then Keywords = Keywords & ", " & c
        Next c
        If Keywords = 0 Then
        Keywords = "-"
    Else
        Keywords = Right(Keywords, Len(Keywords) - 2)
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

Got this from [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/637192-how-capture-multiple-keywords-text-string-using-excel-formula.html).

Comment: Hi, I apologize for my late reply. Yep! it worked just perfect. I am trying to include some other features using macro. I really appreciate your kind Help. God Bless you

Comment: @ChristineShahin - Glad I could help.

Comment: Done, Thank you again